# Getting an error when trying to convert rgb values into their names with the webcolors module

Tags: python, function, tkinter, rgb

I have been struggling with the webcolors module, and when I use the rgb_to_name() function, It raises this/these error(s)(keep in mind im also using the tkinter colorchooser):

File "C:\Users\15CharacterName\PycharmProjects\python\main4.py", line 16, in color_choose
color = webcolors.rgb_to_name(rg_blist)

File "C:\Users\15CharacterName\PycharmProjects\python\venv\lib\site-packages\webcolors.py", line 470, in rgb_to_name return hex_to_name(rgb_to_hex(normalize_integer_triplet(rgb_triplet)), spec=spec)

File "C:\Users\15CharacterName\PycharmProjects\python\venv\lib\site-packages\webcolors.py", line 430, in hex_to_name
raise ValueError("'{}' has no defined color name in {}".format(hex_value, spec))
ValueError: '#56eb62' has no defined color name in css3

Here is the normal code:

```
color = colorchooser.askcolor()
rg_blist = list(color[0])
color = webcolors.rgb_to_name(rg_blist)
```

This is the modified code to check if it was a hexadecimal value(it wasn't):

```
color = colorchooser.askcolor()
rg_blist = list(color[0])
try:
    color = webcolors.rgb_to_name(rg_blist)
except Exception:
    print(rg_blist)
```

output:

[109, 210, 40]

made it print the color variable and reran it- this is what I got:

((105, 150, 216), '#6996d8')
Why is this? I would like to know- I thought it would behave like the .hex_to_name method/function. If an alternate method/function should be used, please notify me!

I'm pretty new to the webcolors module, so it wouldn't suprise me if the answer is simple! Thanks in advance!

Comment: The error seems pretty straightforward. You're trying to look up a name that doesn't exist. Have you verified that`webcolors` should have a name for `#56eb62`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure webcolors uses css3, and css3 doesn't have a name for it. How can I work around this error? (I.e. should I use another module?) Also, why does it interpret the rgb values as a hexadecimal value?

Comment: I don't think all colors have corresponding names.  Why do you insist on getting a name for a color?

Comment: @acw1668 Its for Tkinter, when I try to insert an rgb or hexadecimal values, it raises an error.

Comment: The second item returned by `colorchooser.askcolor()` can be used in tkinter, you don't need to convert the first item `(r, g, b)` to color name actually.

Comment: @acw1668 I also want to get the inverse of the color, and the easiest way to inverse(in my opinion) is iterating over each rgb value and doing 255 - i for each one. Is there a way I can invert a color with hexadecimal values?

Comment: If you just want to get the inverse of the color, you can use the `(r, g, b)` as you said.  But I still don't understand why you need to convert the color to name.

Comment: @acw1668 I also want to display the color and color inverse briefly after the user chooses, in a message box and such.